# "Certificate is bad" in exim smarthost setup

Tags: linux, debian, email, smtp, exim

I am configuring a local exim instance to use an existing server (also exim) as a smart host relay.  This is as verbose as the logs seem to be:

```
2022-06-11 23:59:35.745 [767692] SMTP connection from [173.76.22.149]:54362 I=[10.5.24.98]:587 (TCP/IP connection count = 1)
2022-06-11 23:59:35.849 [767885] TLS error on connection from pool-173-76-22-149.bstnma.fios.verizon.net [173.76.22.149]:54362 I=[10.5.24.98]:587 (recv): A TLS fatal alert has been received: Certificate is bad
2022-06-11 23:59:35.849 [767885] SMTP connection from pool-173-76-22-149.bstnma.fios.verizon.net [173.76.22.149]:54362 I=[10.5.24.98]:587 lost D=0.102s
2022-06-11 23:59:35.849 [767885] no MAIL in SMTP connection from pool-173-76-22-149.bstnma.fios.verizon.net [173.76.22.149]:54362 I=[10.5.24.98]:587 D=0.103s X=TLS1.3:ECDHE_SECP256R1__RSA_PSS_RSAE_SHA256__AES_256_GCM:256 CV=no C=EHLO,STARTTLS
```

It's obviously some kind of certificate problem; I (think I've) turned off all certificate validation, but no help there.  Both servers certs were locally generated (using exim-gencert).  I have tried both direct SSL (port 465) and STARTTLS (port 587); both errors are the same.

Unfortunately the error message doesn't give me much else to go on; where could I look for the source of this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I still don't know why exactly, but I replaced all the certs and it's working now.